# How do I programmatically build up the following Quotation Expression in F#?

Tags: f#

I have a need to access a .NET dictionary within a quotation expression. The following is a simplified version:

```
let mutable dict:Dictionary<string, float> = Dictionary()
dict.Add("first", 1.0)
dict.Add("second", 2.0)
let qe2 = <@ dict.["second"] @>
```

The output of qe2 is as follows:

```
val qe2 : Quotations.Expr<float> =
PropertyGet (Some (PropertyGet (None, dict, [])), Item, [Value ("second")])
```

All is fine when I can directly create the quotation expression directly with quoted code as above. How do I achieve the same thing by building up `qe2` programmatically?

I know that I need to somehow use `Quotations.Expr.PropertyGet` twice in a nested fashion but I don't know how to obtain the neccesary `PropertyInfo and MethodInfo` objects to go about doing that.

Comment: Just a side note... Your `let dict` does not need to be mutable for you to add/modify/remove values from the System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<U,V>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is to know that the `let dict` declaration is compiled as a property on the static module class.

Here is a working sample.

```
module QuotationsTest

open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Reflection

let mutable dict:Dictionary<string, float> = Dictionary()
dict.Add("first", 1.0)
dict.Add("second", 2.0)
let qe2 = <@ dict.["second"] @>

let moduleType = Type.GetType("QuotationsTest")
let dictProp = moduleType.GetProperty("dict", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.Public)   
let indxProp = dict.GetType().GetProperty("Item", [| typeof<string> |])
let qe1 = Expr.PropertyGet(Expr.PropertyGet(dictProp, []), indxProp, [ Expr.Value("first") ])

printfn "%A" qe1
printfn "%A" qe2
```

Compiling and running the above results in the following:

```
> fsc QuotationsTest.fs
Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 12.0.30815.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

> QuotationsTest.exe
PropertyGet (Some (PropertyGet (None, dict, [])), Item, [Value ("first")])
PropertyGet (Some (PropertyGet (None, dict, [])), Item, [Value ("second")])
```